# Robot Framework - Passing List variables as keyword argument

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to use this list of strings as a single keyword argument but get an error at runtime.

> [ ERROR ] Error in file Variables.robot Invalid variable name '${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES}

I can ctrl-click on the ${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES} and it does find the variable within the Variables.robot file

```
Variables.robot

*** Variables ***
${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES} = ["${access_engine_ip}","${analytics_engine_ip}","${AUT_Version}","${browser_type}","${ESX_server_ipaddress}","${device_type_x450_g2}"]

Test.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource Variables.robot
*** Test Cases ***
Initialize Test
    initialize test variables  ${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES}
```

Comment: For one, that doesn't create a list variable. That creates a string variable that looks like a list.

Answer (score 4):

That's not the syntax of creating a list in the Variables section; here's the correct one - you prepend its name with `@`, not `$`, and pass all members separated with at least two spaces:

```
*** Variables ***
@{LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES}    ${access_engine_ip}    ${analytics_engine_ip}   ${AUT_Version}   ${browser_type}    ${ESX_server_ipaddress}    ${device_type_x450_g2}
```

Now in your sample, all the members are references to other variables. `LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES` is instantiated the moment the suite is created - which means all these members have to already have values at this moment - e.g. defined in an imported resource file, or somewhere before the list variable in this file.

If that's not the case - their values are still not set, but that happens a bit later, you can do something different - have a keyword that creates the list variable, sets it with a suite scope; and then call the keyword when needed:

```
*** Variables ***
# the value of this variable is set through the "Set The Value Of The List Var" keyword
${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES}    ${None}    # this "declaration" is not needed, but it's a good practice - thus you show to the other users there is this suite-level var

*** Keywords ***
Set The Value Of The List Var
    ${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES}=     Create List    ${access_engine_ip}    ${analytics_engine_ip}   ${AUT_Version}   ${browser_type}    ${ESX_server_ipaddress}    ${device_type_x450_g2}
    Set Suite Variable    ${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES}
```

You'll call the keyword `Set The Value Of The List Var` when the values of its members are already set, and the list variable will be available for all cases after that call.

Answer (score 3):

What you really want is to define the list in a Python file. Using a Python file makes easier the initialization of variables.

Or correct the syntax like Bryan Oakley pointed. See [User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables)

Example:

```
Variables.py
LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES = ["${access_engine_ip}", "${analytics_engine_ip}", "${AUT_Version}", "${browser_type}", "${ESX_server_ipaddress}", "${device_type_x450_g2}"]

Test.robot
*** Settings ***
Variables         Variables.py

*** Test Cases ***
Initialize Test
    initialize test variables    ${LIST_TEST_ATTRIBUTES}

*** Keywords ***
initialize test variables
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}
    Log    ${arg1}
```